# Event Viewer is not opening

Tags: windows, windows-8, event-viewer

When I double click into Event Viewer in Control Panel, nothing happens. Computer management does not open too. No any error messages displayed.

If I run `eventvwr` from command line, also nothing happens.

**UPDATE**

If run in safe mode, then an exception processing message `0xc0000005` occurs:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

MMC.EXE itself is running, but if trying to add `eventvwr.msc` to it, then it crashes.

Comment: Sounds like your Windows installation is corrupt.

Comment: Is this a personal company or is it subject to things like group policy?

Comment: I don't accept general statement about corruption. What is corrupted? Why it was corrupted? How to fix? The times of Windows 95 when I was meeting with it's install wizard each month, have gone. System should be fixeable by parts.

Comment: @Wutnaut it is my personal notebook. Probably some malicious software blocked this applet by policy yes, how to check it?

Comment: Does it work if you boot Windows into Safe Mode?  Run `chkdsk` to check for disk/file-system corruption, and `SFC /scannow` to check for corrupted system files. Come back and edit the results into your question.

Comment: Do you see it running in Processes under Task Manager? Worth checking and terminating, then attempt to relaunch

Comment: No, event viewer (something event*, evt*) is not present in task manager details section. When I am trying to run it, `dllhost', 'WerFault', 'mmc.exe' processes appear in task manager for some tim, then disappear. Nothing on screen appears.

Comment: My Event Viewer runs as "mmc.exe", so the fact that you see it opening and then terminating is a nice clue and good progression.

Comment: @Dims - I know I must sound like a broken record but the fact your getting a exception when you launch the event viewer you have serious system integrity issues

Comment: @Ramhound, I agree, but what you suggest? Except reinstalltion.

Comment: Still waiting on you to run the command that should fix any problems that was suggested an hour ago by somebody else.

Comment: Doing all possible commands...

Comment: Have you tried using NirSoft's MyEventViewer? Just one warning, it could get a little heavy on resources depending on the log's size.

Comment: Yes tried. It took long time to load all events, but apparently Schannel events are gone

Comment: @Dims I've just noticed that during the last 12 hours you've opened about 5 questions, and I assume they are regarding the same personal computer .
The overall picture is that something went really wrong with your computer (probably a virus), and now I'm with Ramhound about reinstalling.
From my experience, unless you've got a lot of spare time and patience, it's not worth the effort.
If you're still keen on the idea of fixing it, I'd still suggest reinstalling, but take first an image of your current machine and put it inside a VM.
One more idea, try monitoring the activity with ProcMon.

Comment: when you see this error message, use ProcExplorer and create a mini dump of the mmc.exe. upload the dmp file

Comment: have you captured the dump?